# Meaning of expression: "Hay mucho que hablar del bacalao ."

Tags: modismos

Meaning of modismo: "Hay mucho que hablar del bacalao.

Comment: @walen - Do you happen to have an English version of that handy for post authors who have written their question in English?  Because it's hard to know how well a newcomer who writes their question in English will understand Spanish.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's an advertising slogan more than a *modismo*, as far as I can tell.  Here's an explanation I found:

> Hace años, en la entonces única televisión al alcance de todos los españoles, solían emitirse campañas más o menos institucionales que trataban de fomentar el consumo de ciertos productos, siempre en plan 'genérico', esto es, sin marca comercial. Uno de ellos fue el bacalao.
>
> «Hay mucho que hablar del bacalao», repetía machaconamente la televisión. La verdad es que el pobre bacalao no gozaba, por entonces, de muy buena prensa, salvo en el País Vasco.

I think that "Hay much que hablar" is a shortened form of "Hay much de que hablar," which means, *There's a lot to talk about*.  In this case, it's *There's a lot to be said about bacalao*.  Which I think is cod (maybe the salted kind, which you may have heard of on Prairie Home Companion as lutefisk).

Side note: Here's a fun phrase involving *bacalao*: *Te conozco, bacalao, aunque vengas disfrazao*.  (*Disfrazao = disfrazado*.)  You get to say this to a friend in a teasing way.  For example, if your friend shows up late to dinner, and you say, "Don't worry, I made a dinner that could sit warming in the oven for a while, in case you were late, because *te conozco, bacalao, aunque vengas disfrazao* (I know what you're like -- you can't put one over on me!).